# How to parametrize a SQL statement

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a statement as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASK IESWEBSERP.MASK_PWD_WSCONTROL 
ON IESWEBSERP.WSCONTROL
FOR COLUMN WSVNDPWD    
    RETURN                                         
        CASE   
            WHEN (VERIFY_GROUP_FOR_USER(SESSION_USER, 'xxx', 'xxxx') = 1)
                THEN WSVNDPWD                                                              
            WHEN (SESSION_USER IN ('QSQSRVR', 'QTMHHTTP', 'PROFOUNDJS', 'xxxx'))                  
                THEN WSVNDPWD  
            WHEN IESWEBSERP.IES_CHECK_AUTH(WSDTALIB) = 1        
                THEN WSVNDPWD
            WHEN (WSVNDID  = IESWEBSERP.web_login_id)
                THEN WSVNDPWD 
            ELSE 'MASKED'
    END
```

I am trying to parametrize this in a way that will allow me to pass a table name and run this statement for that particular table. Is there any approach to make this possible?

Comment: On i-series `create mask` can be dynamically prepared. So either create a routine that uses dynamic-SQL to achieve what you need, or script with whatever scripting toolset is available at your site.